# How to find the norm for 'L + U' in LU decomposition

Tags: python

I am new to Python 3 and currently learning about LU Decomposition and how to express its functions in Python. We were given as a class a question that involves writing a code in order to find the LU decomposition of a matrix `A` (using scipy) as well as the norm of 'L+U' within that decomposition. I understand how to get P L and U with scipy.linalg.lu but I am having trouble understanding how to add L and U together after getting that answer. this is my code so far...

```
from numpy import array, sqrt
import scipy as sp
from scipy.linalg import norm   



def scipy_LU(A):

    Q = sp.linalg.lu(A)
    print(Q)


elements_of_A = list(map(float, input(). split(' '))) 
order = int(sqrt(len(elements_of_A)))
A = array(elements_of_A).reshape(order, order)
print(round(norm(L+U, 1), 4))
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? In your code sample `L` and `U` are not defined.

Comment: ah thank you I see what you mean

Answer (score 1):

The return of `scipy.linalg.lu` is three separate matrices: `P`, `L`, and `U`.  Rather than assigning them as a tuple to the variable `Q`, you can assign it to 3 variables, compute the addition, and then compute the norm:

```
def norm_LU(A):

    P, L, U = sp.linalg.lu(A)
    L_plus_U = L + U
    return norm(L_plus_U)
```